# setvalues() using only one cell in a specific range ex.("A3" in "A3:B4")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code is entered only when a specific range is entered.

```
spreadsheet.getRange("A3:B4").setValues([[1,2],[1,33]]);
```

Desired result

[image]

I don't want to specify a specific range ("A3:B4"). 
I want to specify a range starting at A3 that is expandable depending on the value of a variable.
Using one location (A3), I want to input an array of values from that cell.
Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)/[google-sheets-api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update):

```
//@see https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(
  { values: array }, 
  "SpreadsheetID",
  "Sheet1!A3",
  { valueInputOption: "RAW" }
);
```